# Can a Scala class extend multiple classes?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to extend multiple classes in Scala.

For example if I have ClassA and ClassB then can ClassC extend ClassA and ClassB (like in C++).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, `ClassC` just can extend one of those, but you can mixin multiple traits.

Answer (score 48):

You can't extend multiple classes, but you can extend several traits. Unlike Java interfaces, traits can also include implementation (method definitions, data members, etc.). There is still a difference in that you can't instantiate a trait directly (similar to abstract classes in a way).

```
trait T1
trait T2
trait T3
class C extends T1 with T2 with T3
```

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Not quite, Java 8 introduced default methods, but still no (not even `abstract`) fields to interfaces.